# Linq query cant be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have these queries:

```
 weathers = query.Skip(args.Skip.Value).Take(args.Top.Value).ToList<Weather>();
    
 List<IGrouping<int, Weather>> averages = context.Weathers
     .Where(w => weathers.Select(lw => lw.Date.DayOfYear).Contains(w.Date.DayOfYear))
     .GroupBy(w => w.Date.DayOfYear).ToList();
```

the second query can't be translated, I want to group a series of weather entities by their Date's dayofyear.

There is a List of weathers that I first load (for example 10 weathers) and then go to database and for each of them load previous years (in the same day) weathers.

How to make this query to work?

Comment: Perhaps try it without the `.ToList` on the weathers query? I haven't tried it and I don't use EF myself, but it seems more likely to be able to translate that.

Comment: Can you specify which DBMS you used? MSSQL, Postgre, MySQL?

Comment: I use Sqlite, using EF core Sqlite package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

```cs
var averages1 = context.Weathers
      .Where(w => weathers.Select(lw => lw.Date.DayOfYear).Contains(w.Date.DayOfYear))
      .ToList();
      
averages = averages1.GroupBy(w => w.Date.DayOfYear).ToList();
```

it will not have a performance problem.

Comment: You can use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`. It should be the same result, without the overhead of creating a list. It is about loading the data from the database the memory and execute your `GroupBy()` localy and not by the database.

Comment: If you solved your question mark your answer as correct to mark the answer as solved.